# Custom android Spinner?

Tags: android, spinner

I need a small help regarding the spinner,when i click any part of the spinner popup need to displayed, but by default we will get the popup by clicking on the right side of the  spinner? sry for my English..

1.when i click on the center of spinner also popup need to be displayed.

thanks,
Nikhilreddy

Comment: The arrow will be on right side, but on cliking anywhere it does show the items. try out. If you still face problems, post your code you use to set your Spinner.

Comment: Check [this](http://bountyforu.blogspot.in/2013/06/custom-spinner-winners-in-world-of.html), really good explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please use custom spinner like
 - take one textview and set the  background of textview such like spinner
 - then use below code :

```
TextView tx;
String[] s = { "India ", "Arica", "India ", "Arica", "India ", "Arica",
        "India ", "Arica", "India ", "Arica" };
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final ArrayAdapter<String> adp = new ArrayAdapter<String>(WvActivity.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, s);

    tx= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt1);
    tx.setOnClickListener(new  View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(WvActivity.this);
            builder.setAdapter(adp,new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    tx.setText(s[which]);
                }
            });
            builder.create().show();
        }

    });

}
```

i think this will help u better

Answer (score 0):

When I'm doing like this :

```
String[] items = new String[] {"One", "Two", "Three"};
        Spinner sp = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.myspinner);
        ArrayAdapter<String> ars = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items);
        ars.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        sp.setAdapter(ars);
```

I do not have any problem when clicking any part of the spinner I always display the popup...